# Difference between PXProcessing and PXFilteredProcessing in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I want to know what is the Difference between PXProcessing and PXFilteredProcessing in Acumatica

Answer (score 1):

PXFilteredProcessing is for when you have a FormDetail screen, with a PXFilter data view as your main data view on the header form. It makes it so that the Process and Process all actions appear properly. If you just have a ListView screen, use PXProcessing instead. They are functionally identical except for this.